# Just started coding in html and css but i'm stuck at making the picture seeable through the navigation bar

Tags: html, css

As you saw above i can't get the picture seeable through the navigation bar. Keep in mind i just started and i got no experience. This is what i got and don't know where to go from here.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="sights.html">Sights</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="sakura.html">Sakura</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  background-image: url(pic1.jpg);
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 10, 173, 0.27);
  padding: 20px;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(170, 19, 120, 1);
}
nav li a:hover, .active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 77, 181, 0.87);
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the expected output:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any picture referenced in your code?

Comment: now there is one XD
but now i want to make that page a slideshow but it isn't gonna work that way so i need help here again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are lookging for is the `opacity` attribute.

Try adding:

`opacity: 0.5;`

to your `nav li a` CSS and see if that helps!

Comment: that's not it. i can't get the picture to start from the top and be seeable through the navbar. where ever i add the <img src> in html the picture goes from the menu downwards or replaces the menu to the bottom. the picture in the post is how i would like it to look but i can't get the image under the navbar.

Comment: You need to either use absolute positioning on the photo, or, more likely, set it as the background for the entire <body>.  Then either use the opacity on the LI as suggested or wrap your nav in a defined DIV with opacity set on it.